# Custom file template for C files in CLion

Tags: c, linux, velocity, clion

I want to create author header for C file in *CLion* (it use **Apache Velocity template language**) which looks like this:

```
/*********************************/
/* ${FILE_NAME}                  */
/*                               */
/* By: ${USER}                   */
/*                               */
/* Created: ${DATE} by ${USER}   */
/* Updated: ${??} by ${USER}     */
/*                               */
/*********************************/
```

There are two problems:

1. How to add `Updated date` and how can I change it format?
2. I want to fix the width of header, now its width varies depending on length of the `FILE_NAME` and `USER`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems we are discussing Copyright comment.
[Here is](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copyright.html) the description. `$today` macro is your choice.

Comment: My bad. I need to fix it.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-10423